# Tailwind vertical border in middle of div

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Tailwind border documentation is plain and clear, you can do border top, bottom, right and left. You can do a vertical by using the height feature, and a horizontal by width, understandable. Question is how can I find the center of div and create a vertical border on top/bottom from there? Same goes for right and left.

```js
    <div class="p-10">
      <div className="p-10 mx-auto w-fit border-t border-pink-200 grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
        
        <div class="p-5 m-5 border border-sky-200">
          <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="p-5 m-5 border border-sky-200">
          <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="p-5 m-5 border border-sky-200">
          <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

A photo of current website design is https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2cbD.png and the yellow lines are the ones I drew with a tool, of what I expect the borders to look like.

is there any way to do these on tailwind? Thank you!

Comment: maybe you could have a div with a yellow border in between your elements instead of using padding

Comment: thats not how html / css works directly. You have to work a bit more to get that. The standard border classes in tailwind are just wrapping the css border property.

Answer (score 0):

You can create it with pseudo elements like below:

```
before:w-px before:h-16 before:bg-yellow-400 before:absolute before:left-1/2 before:-translate-x-1/2 before:bottom-full
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="p-10">
  <div class="p-10 mx-auto w-fit border-t border-pink-200 grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">

    <div class="p-5 m-5 relative border border-sky-200 before:w-px before:h-16 before:bg-yellow-400 before:absolute before:left-1/2 before:-translate-x-1/2 before:bottom-full after:h-px after:w-16 after:bg-yellow-400 after:absolute after:top-1/2 after:-translate-y-1/2 after:left-full">
      <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="p-5 m-5 border border-sky-200">
      <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="p-5 m-5 border border-sky-200">
      <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it using the border? I need it to be more interactive, so when you click a specific thing change the color etc.

Comment: you can't do it with `border`. and you can change the color whenever you want.

Comment: like `hover:before:bg-blue-200`